# chart is not rendering properly, canvasjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvasjs

I'm trying to render two dynamic charts using `canvasJS`, Chart one is rendering properly, in fact second chart is populating properly, please see the `inspect element` image, but it's not displaying on the page.

This is interface, just one chart is displaying 
[image]

and here is inspect elem.[image]

`#adverts` is rendering, but not displayed here.

```
.chartContainer{
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

**PS** I tried to commented out first chart rendering code, but not working at all, still displaying the first one only.

**EDIT**

Here is `console log` about what I'm getting back to render chart

[image]

here is snippet

```
function drawChart(obj, placeholder, From, To){
var legendFrom;
var legendTo;
if(From != 'undefined'){
    legendFrom = From;
}
if(To != 'undefined'){
    legendTo = To;
}
var dataPoints = [];
var from = [];
var to = [];
var advertFrom = [];
var advertTo = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= obj.length - 1; i++) {
    if(obj[i].typeOf != 'undefined' || obj[i].typeOf != ''){
        if(obj[i].typeOf == 'from'){
            from.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:Math.round(obj[i].avgPrice * 1000) / 1000});
            advertFrom.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:obj[i].adverts});
        }else{
            to.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:Math.round(obj[i].avgPrice * 1000) / 1000});
            advertTo.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:obj[i].adverts});
        }
    }
    else
        from.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:Math.round(obj[i].avgPrice * 1000) / 1000});
}
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{
    animationEnabled: true,
    //theme: "theme1",
    zoomEnabled: true,
    title:{
        text: placeholder
    },
    data: [
        {
            type: "spline",  //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "From "+legendFrom, 
            dataPoints: from
        },
        {
            type: "spline",  
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "From "+legendTo, 
            dataPoints: to
        }
    ],
    legend: {
        cursor: "pointer",
        itemclick: function (e) {
            if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                e.dataSeries.visible = false;
            } else {
                e.dataSeries.visible = true;
        }
        chart.render();
        }
    }
});

chart.render();
var adverts = new CanvasJS.Chart("adverts",
{
    animationEnabled: true,
    zoomEnabled: true,
    title:{
        text: placeholder
    },
    data: [
        {
            type: "column",  //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "From "+legendFrom, 
            dataPoints: advertFrom
        },
        {
            type: "column",  
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "From "+legendTo, 
            dataPoints: advertTo
        }
    ]
});
adverts.render();
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code you used to populate these graphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just replicated a canvasJS enviroment in JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/fLbngdv9/1/

Make sure you are are using a new VAR for each chart.

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {..});
chart.render();
var chart2 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", {..});
chart2.render();
```

Seems to work fine. If you can provide me with some code examples then perhaps I can help you find an answer.

Probably just a copy paste mistake but you have a syntax error at the very bottom.

```
...
adverts.render();
}
```

This should be

```
...
adverts.render();
```

Just remove the extra bracket. I updated the JS Fiddle to be more like your example... [[here]](http://jsfiddle.net/fLbngdv9/2/)

**Edit:**

I was able to replicate in my latest JSFiddle and I know this sounds crazy but when I changed the ID of your second div from adverts to chartContainer2 it worked fine.

Still investigating as to why this is but I would try renaming the ID on the div and also the reference for the graphs creation.

[SEE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fLbngdv9/4/)

**Edit 2:**

This appears to be a Chrome specific bug with the ID adverts. To replicate all you need to do is check out this link http://www.briangebel.com/test.html

[image]

(As you can see the div Adverts is hidden in Chrome but visible on FF,Opera,IE)

So what is happening..

1. Chrome's **ADBlocker** extension sees this ID and automatically adds an in page stylesheet.
2. This style sheet has the following Style

[image]

3. This only affects Chrome as it is caused by a specific extension. (I am attempting to contact the developer to see if he can resolve this but until then follow the below solution)

**Solution**

Simple don't use that ID. (You could simply disable AdBlocker but this extension is so widely used I would still recommend changing the ID)

Comment: I've added `snippet` and image to `object`'s log that is being rendered.

Comment: `}` is closing bracket of function, not working on my machine, don't know what I'm doing wrong :( , doing exactly same, but only getting the one chart, no error either

Comment: Did you check out my updated JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/fLbngdv9/2/
Any way you could link me to the page? Or replicate the issue in JSFiddle?

Comment: http://urbane.solutions/CaPriSeTool/mobile.de/chart.php , go here Select a `make` and hit `Refresh` button, it's not getting stuff from database properly, but somehow, it's getting some results, that will let you know the problem, if you view `console` you can see the object that is coming back from server(`PHP` page) and the file name that is being used to render the charts is `perModalChart.js`

Comment: @MubinKhalid I updated my answer with a final solution. Luckily it appears to be quite easy! ;) Good Luck

Comment: that was a really really great help, Thank you very much. :) love you :*

Comment: @MubinKhalid Haha No problem. Also if you are interested my coworker helped me narrow it down to Chrome's AdBlocker extension. If you disable the extension it should work fine... However, this extension is so widely used I would still recomend changing the ID

Comment: one more thing, when I try to render the second chart, it doesn't displays any data, can you please guide?